# Virtual Machine on a flashdrive

Tags: virtual-machine, usb-flash-drive

Is it a good idea to have a virtual machine in a flash drive? Since operating systems frequently read & write,  would this degrade the flash drive very quickly? Right now, I have a virtual machine residing in an external harddrive, but the issue is that it is not very convenient or portable. On the other hand, I have seen products like this : [http://www.amazon.com/VisionTek-120GB-Pocket-Drive-900718/dp/B00O0NV5HU](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00O0NV5HU), though I am not sure of their quality.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it would kill regular flash drive quickly, my guess is 3 months lifespan at best.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Short answer** : 
Yes it is an ok  idea to have a VM on a flash disk but there are better alternatives. From looking at the specs of the flash disk it'll be fine

Write speeds for a 3.71gb file were 70mb/s on this disk. From my experience with flash disk it should last atleast a year. Unless you really want to do serious heavy duty stuff

**Long answer**:
Using a virtual machine isn't recommended unless absolutly necessary (in which case you probably need). It will degrade the disk but like any nand  disk it'll wear down. Except now disks and OS's are a lot more optimal for this

**My recommendation**:
If you really want an operating system to work at its best, use Rufus to install Windows or the Linux distro installer. So then you can directly boot the disk